# Using '*' instead of '+' in a regex check

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex check:

```
Match matchLeft = Regex.Match(Name.Substring(subName.Length), @"\d*");
```

This basically checks for the first digits at the end of the `subName`. Now, I have noticed that with the use of `*` in the regex (`*` = 0 or more), if the next characters *are not* digits, it will return nothing. If they are however, it will return the string of digits.

*But*

If I use `@"\d+"` instead, it will look for *1 or more* digits, and return the first instance of digits, regardless of there position after the substring.

So if I had a string ("abcdef123") and a substring ("abc"):

- `@"\d*"` would match `null`
- `@"\d+"` would match "123"

Alternatively, if the substring was "abcdef", both would match "123".

So my question is - why does the use of `*` return nothing if the directly following characters are *not* digits? Will this occur *every time*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the substring you end up with `def123`.  The following are true:

- `\d+` tries to get at least one match in the string and will greedily match more.  It must traverse the string to find the first match, arriving at the 123.
- On the other hand, `\d*` will start at the beginning of the string and will successfully match the start of the string with *zero* digits.  Even though it is greedy, it is completely satisfied with matching zero digits.  **It is a successful match** and is zero-width.

You can change this behavior by making it `\d*$` to anchor at the end of the matched string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your question yourself. This behavior is default and will occur every time.

See [*Quantifier Cheat Sheet*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet)

> **A+**
>     **One or more As**, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)
>
> **A***
>   **Zero or more As**, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)

Since `\d*` can match an empty string it will match an empty string as regex engine always tries to return a valid match, and can even match empty substrings at the beginning, end and between characters in a string.